# Why does the navfn plan a path through a wall

Tags: ros, navigation, path, navfn, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,all, we are using [navfn in move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/navfn?distro=lunar) to plan a global path for a robot.
For now, the experiments are being done in a simulated environment by gazebo.
However, we found that if the robot is close to a wall, if a goal is on the another side of the wall, the generated path from navfn often goes through the wall.  Please see the below two images.

The first image shows the generated path when the inflation layer is canceled. The second image shows the generated path with a running inflation layer. Both of these two path go through the wall.

I have read a similiar question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/157296/navfn-planning-through-wall/). But the walls in  the illustrated instance are intermittent(not constantly). On the contrary, as you can see from the below images, the walls are constantly(unintermittent).

Is this a bug of navfun?
Looking forwards to any advices to improve navfn!  Thanks!

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274046/why-does-the-navfn-plan-a-path-through-a-wall/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2017-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try setting allow_unknown to false.
http://wiki.ros.org/navfn#Parameters

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2017-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2017-10-31**:
Thank you very much! We checked the vaule of allow_unknow. It was alrealy "false". And in obstacle layer, the track_unknown_space was also set to be true as needed. The problem still exists.